# $a_{n+1}=a_n-a^2_n$ show the recursion sequence is convergent and find its limit

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

> Let $a_1=\frac 2 3 , \ a_{n+1}=a_n-a^2_n$ for $n\ge 1$.
>
> Show the sequence is convergent and find its limit.

In order to show convergence, I need to show that it's monotone and bounded.

Showing it's bounded: $0\le a_{n+1}\le 1$ by induction, for $n=1$ it's true, so suppose it's true for $n$ and prove for $n+1$ so: $a_{n+1} = a_n-a^2_n\le 1$, by the induction hypothesis, define $0<b<1$ so:  $a_{n+1} \le 1-b \Rightarrow 0\le a_{n+1} \le 1$.

I tried the usual method of showing the sequence is monotone: $\dfrac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}\ge 1$ but that doesn't lead anywhere.

As for the limit, since $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n+1} = L$ so: $L=L-L^2\Rightarrow L^2=0 \Rightarrow L=0$.

Other than showing the sequence is monotone, please let me know if I missed anything regarding formality.

Comment: $a_{n+1} - a_n = -a_n^2 \le 0$

Comment: @peterwhy, you meant plus instead of minus: $a_{n\color{red}{+}1}$, also why is it true ?

Comment: It comes from your recursion: $a_{n+1} = a_n - a_n^2$, and since $a_n^2$ is always non-negative, it means your sequence is not increasing but decreasing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly if $0<a_n<1$ then $0<a_n(1-a_n)=a_{n+1}<a_n<1$

$\{a_n\}$ is bounded below by $0$ and decreasing. [Hence converges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem) to $l$ such that $l=l-l^2\Rightarrow l=0$